# TreeSet with Entry

Tags: java, data-structures, treeset

I'm testing out and trying to learn a bit about TreeSet.

Still i cant figure out how to implement something that returns this type:

```
TreeSet<Entry<String, Long>>
```

Really confused.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are actually have a `TreeMap<String, Long>`?

Comment: `new TreeSet<Entry<String, Long>>()` ?

Comment: Do you want a `TreeMap`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: you need understand what is TreeSet, genereally its a Map :) yes, TreeMap, but for TreeSet functionality using just a Key column and Value as default, so, if you understand it you will get answer :). There are a good point in comments, but I think you dont understand what do you want ...

Comment: Good point Sergii :) Im lost, haha.

Well, TreeMap seems to solve it. Still i have to cast ti to TreeSet. TreeSet doesnt take 2 args without a Entry as i see it. And you cant just add 2 values to an created TreeSet with Entry.

Answer (score 0):

i also new in treeset but what im understand is the code is calling another treeset entry into the new TreeSet. correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you need Entry in TreeSet you must implement Map.Entry interface in your own. Its pretty simple interface